# Maven version number output in echo rounds up value

Tags: bash, maven, echo

I am trying to get the version number of my maven project using the following line of code below in Command Line. But when I try set it as a value in my bash script using 
**version_num = $(...)** it stays rounding it up to a value of **1** when its assigned to that variable. The expected result should be **0.8**

```
version_num = "$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version|grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)')"
```

Comment: That's not a valid assignment line with the spaces around the `=`. Is that the actual line from your script? How are you checking the value of the variable?

Comment: There is no rounding here, output of your command is indeed `1`

Comment: Why do you need it? Where do you need it?

Comment: I need it because when I am making a script for my continuous integration app, I need to take out the version number from the pom.xml file in maven. and put that version number in my build version in my appengine deployment xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the maven resource plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Basically the idea is that upon building your application, you will filter some of your project files (in your case deployment.xml) to replace some text with what you want (in your case version number).